# Размещение TextView по верх ViewPager

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager

Есть `ViewPager` и `TextView` нужно сделать так чтобы `TextView` отображался по верх `ViewPager`. Я пробовал `RelativeLayout` и `ConstraintLayout` что бы реализовать это но постоянно картинка которая находиться в `ViewPager` перекрывает `TextView`. Как сделать чтобы `TextView` был над `ViewPager`?

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_o"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_2"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_2" />

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_2" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разместите TextView в самом конце вашего RelativeLayout. Чем ниже элемент в списке, тем выше остальных элементов (по оси Z) он находится на разметке.

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

 ...
 ...

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_o"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_2"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```